# Plasmashell task has a memory leak but dumping /proc/$pid/maps is not leading to the culprit

Tags: plasma5

I have a memory leak in my plasmashell task running on my openSuse Leap 15.4 system. I periodically dumped the /proc/$pid/map of the plasmashell pid and took the difference of two logs

```
< 7fa3b795c000-7fa3b79d4000 rw-s 00000000 00:01 15204415                   /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
---
> 7fa3b7950000-7fa3b79c8000 rw-s 00000000 00:01 15302703                   /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
```

Please note the increase in size from 15204415 to 15302703, showing that system RAM is slowly being eaten.

I did look up /SYSV00000000 on the internet, but it is shared memory content.

How can I get more definitive about this and accurately locate the memory leak?

The current Plasma desktop details are

```
Operating System: openSUSE Leap 15.4
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.90.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Kernel Version: 5.14.21-150400.24.28-default (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 6 × Intel® Xeon® CPU E5-1650 v2 @ 3.50GHz
Memory: 31.3 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: llvmpipe
```

How would you proceed?

Right now, my only solution is to attach running tasks to pid 1 using the setsid() command, and then logging out of the Plasma5 session, then logging back in on a new session, only to repeat this process endlessly in an effort to avoid system RAM being consumed.

Comment: Is there some reason, other than what’s in the question, that makes you think ram is being consumed?

Answer (score 1):

James:
I found the answer to my problem, it was the slideshow option for the KDE Desktop which caused the problem, I turned it off and the memory leak stopped. I actually dumped data periodically from the /proc/self/maps area and took diffs, and after turning off the slideshow, the problem did not show up in the log files diffs anymore. In regard to your question, I was using "htop" to look at % of system memory the plasmashell task was consuming. I assume that this is system RAM.
But in any case the problem has been resolved.

Comment: this answer also helped me with the same issue. plasma 5.27.4 on ubuntu lunar.